# How can I search for a particular record in mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb, web-applications

- my collection name is *books*
- the collection's fields are: *bookname*, *cost*, *date*

In my web application suppose I want to search for a particular bookname, then how can I search it in php using mongodb as a backend?

Comment: Hi Rohit Borude and welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like you need a basic introduction to querying MongoDB through PHP; in that case, Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask. This site is for asking specific questions about specific problems in your programming, not for asking general questions about how to start programming.

Answer (score 0):

Using MongoClient, following is the code;

```
$results = $collection->find(array(
'bookname' => {bookname}
    ), array('bookname', 'cost', 'date'));
```

Regards,
Zubair